# NSDateFormatter for "1 January 2014"

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Before read it fully, don't marked it as duplicate. This type of question asked many times. But I've searched but not found answer for my case. Question is simple, I want to show date string as 
**1 January 2014**. I've used date format as below

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy"];
self.model.dateOfBirth =  [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.dobDatepicker.date];
```

But It give **1 january 2014** with the month not capitalized. What is the correct format if I want the output as **1 January 2014**?

**Update:** According to @rmaddy, I've tried this,

```
NSLog(@"DAte %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.dobDatepicker.date]);
NSString *date = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.dobDatepicker.date];
self.model.dateOfBirth =  date;
```

It show in log as **1 January 2014**. But when I assign as text in textfield, it show as
**1 january 2014**.

```
self.dobTextField.text = self.model.dateOfBirth;
```

I couldn't find what is an issue?

Comment: What is your locale? For `en_US` I get the month with a capital letter.

Comment: yes. My locale is `en_US`.

Comment: Show a bit more of your code.

Comment: Try this - assign the result of `stringFromDate:` to a local `NSString` variable and log that value. Then assign that string to your `dateOfBirth` property. What does the log show?

Comment: @iMani in my tab sunnys answer not visible at that time i can send answer

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya K K. But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @iMani check my updated answer this was perfect.

Comment: @iMani So this proves that your date format is just fine. Somewhere you must be using `lowercaseString` with your `dateOfBirth` property. Do you have a custom setter for the property?

Comment: @rmaddy surely not. I've checked with my entire project. No, I didn't use custom textfield or custom property.

Comment: Use your debugger and step through the code and look at the values. Somewhere between getting the value from `stringFromData:` and assigning the value to the text field the value changes to lowercase. You need to find where. Or is there something about your text field that forces the text to lowercase? Do a search on `lowercaseString`.

Comment: Ya already searched with `lowercaseString`. K I'll check with steps through..

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya Please read the comments and the updated question. This issue has nothing at all to do with the date formatting. It's something after that.

Comment: I'm doing research with this. Why it is not working? All are posting correct but doesn't work for me.. Why?.

Answer (score 3):

```
LLLL stand-alone form
MMMM format forms



 L/LL:  1~12 (0 padded Month)
LLL:    Jan/Feb/Mar/Apr/May/Jun/Jul/Aug/Sep/Oct/Nov/Dec
LLLL:   January/February/March/April/May/June/July/August/September/October/November/Deacember





[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd LLLL yyyy"];
```

Comment: Please explain why `LLLL` will work better than `MMMM`.

Comment: +1 It works with LLLL strange i didn't knew we can use L instead of M.

Comment: @Sunnyshah Nothing in that link would lead to a difference in case between using `MMMM` and `LLLL`.

Comment: @Sunnyshah Curious, do you see any difference between using `MMMM` and `LLLL` as related to the issue by the OP? It works for just fine using `MMMM`.

Comment: if your language would always capitalize a date symbol such as month name or weekday name when it appears by itself on a calendar page or as a menu item (but not when it appears in the middle of a sentence), then stand-alone forms may be used for capitalized versions of date symbols

Comment: @Sunnyshah As can be seen by the OP's updated question, there is nothing wrong with the date format. The issue is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

i test your code it works perfectly. check your project some where you have made mistaken.

[image]

```
- (void)redrawDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy"];

    dateLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:selectedDate];


}

- (IBAction)changeDate:(id)sender
{
    DateTimePicker *controller = [[DateTimePicker alloc] init];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.defaultDate = selectedDate;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void)dateTimePickerOK:(DateTimePicker *)controller didPickDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    self.selectedDate = date;
    [self redrawDate];

    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)dateTimePickerCancel:(DateTimePicker *)controller
{
[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `stringWithFormat:` to assign `stringFromData:` to the label?

Comment: @rmaddy i just working some other project so far i copied and used. thanks for your valuable support